# Bounded Analytic Functions on Parabolic Riemann surfaces are constant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading the book on Riemann Surfaces by Farkas and Kra (third edition). When proving uniformization theorem for nonhyperbolic simply connected Riemann surfaces, they say that bounded analytic functions on parabolic Riemann surfaces are constant. There is no result saying it explictly. Why is it true?

Comment: Does it mean a Riemann surface whose universal cover is $\Bbb{C}$? If so then your bounded analytic function gives a bounded entire function on $\Bbb{C}$. More generally any bounded analytic function on a Riemann surface which can be compactified by adding a few isolated points will be constant.

Comment: @reuns I understood that we go twoards such a result. But, using Farkas and Kra approach, as a consequence of what one may prove that bounded analytic functions are constant? Do they assume a maximum value?

Comment: There are a few different proofs of Liouville's theorem, but the one generalizing better is to say that if $f$ is entire and bounded then $z^2 f(1/z)$ is holomorphic thus  analytic at $0$, so $f(1/z)$ is either analytic or has a pole, but $f$ is bounded so $f(1/z)$ is analytic, whence $f$ attains its maximum at a point (can be $\infty$) where it is analytic which implies that it is constant (locally a non-constant analytic function is $=A+Bw^n+O(w^{n+1})$ it has no local maximum)

Comment: But you can use Liouville Theorem since you know that such a surface is biholomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Actually, they are proving such a result. To get the thesis, they want to prove the existence of an admissible function at a point $P$. Well, at the end of the proof they observe that a bounded analytic function on $M$ is constant, without no proof.

Comment: We just need a non-constant holomorphic map from $\Bbb{C}$ to the Riemann surface to get the bounded entire function (assuming the Riemann surface is connected so that locally constant implies globally constant). That's why I asked the meaning of parabolic.

Comment: Parabolic=M is not constant and does not carry a negative non-constant subharmonic function. I need an answer  based on what Farkas and Kra write within their book.

Comment: If $f$ is bounded analytic non-constant then $\Re(f)- C$ is negative non-constant harmonic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP didn't define parabolic: a Riemann surface with no non-constant negative subharmonic functions. If $f$ is analytic bounded non-constant then $\Re(f)-C$ (with $C>\sup |f|$) is non-constant negative harmonic.